# How to calculate the derivative of $f(x) = x^{\frac{2}{3}}$ directly from the definition?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

I'm having trouble taking the derivative of $f(x)=x^{2/3}$ by defining limits.

If anyone can help me, I would be very grateful. I'm looking to calculate the following limit directly:

$$\lim_{h \to 0} 
\frac
{ (x+h)^{\frac{2}{3}} - x^{\frac{2}{3}}}
{h}$$

Comment: What are your tries?

Comment: Yet another problem solvable with [AGM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means).

Comment: Rationalize the numerator.

Comment: SImilar: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3856278

Comment: I multiplied it by the conjugate of the function, but I ended up getting an unwanted result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $A^3-B^3=(A-B) (A^2+AB+B^2) $.

Apply it for $A=\sqrt[3]{(x+h)^2}$ and $B=\sqrt[3]{x^2}$

Answer (score 3):

By the first principle definition, we have the derivative,
$$\lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{(x+h)^{2/3} - x^{2/3}}{h}$$

I hope you are allowed to use, ${\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{x^{n} - a^{n}}{x-a} = n a^{n-1}} $

So,
$$\lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{(x+h)^{2/3} - x^{2/3}}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{(x+h)^{2/3} - x^{2/3}}{(x+h) - x} = \dfrac23 x^{2/3 - 1} =  \dfrac23 x^{-1/3} $$

Answer (score 0):

Here's a general method for any rational $0 < m/n < 1$ that uses mean inequalities, which notably can be proven with no calculus.

By the arithmetic-geometric mean inequality, for any positive real numbers $a,b$ and integers $n>m>0$,
$$
(a^m b^{n-m})^{1/n} \le \frac{m a + (n-m)b }{n}  = b+\frac{m}{n}(a-b),
$$
and by the geometric-harmonic mean inequality,
$$
(a^m b^{n-m})^{1/m}\ge\frac{nab}{mb +(n-m)a} = \frac{mb(a-b)}{n b +(n-m)(a-b)}+b.
$$
Now plug in $a = x+h$ and $b = x$ and simplify to get
$$
\frac{m}{n}\frac{h}{ 1 + (1-\frac{m}{n})\frac{h}{x}}+x\le (x+h)^{m/n}x^{1-m/n}\le \frac{m}{n}h + x.
$$
Can you see how to get the limit from here?